# Prove: If $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0$ $ \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ $g(x)\gt 0 $ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L \gt0$
>
> Prove that
>
> 1.) If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$
>
> 2.) Conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0 \iff \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$

1.) Using the definition of limits:

$\forall \epsilon_1 \gt 0$, $N_1 \gt 0$

$$ x\gt N_1  \Rightarrow |g(x)| \lt \epsilon_1$$

$\forall \epsilon_0 \gt 0$, $N_0 \gt 0$

$$ x \gt N_0  \Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\right| \lt \epsilon_0$$

Now doing a little bit of algebra:

$$g(x)(-\epsilon_0+L)\lt f(x) \lt g(x)(\epsilon_0+L)$$

And using the fact that $|g(x)| \lt \epsilon_1$:

$$-\epsilon_1(-\epsilon_0+L) \le g(x)(-\epsilon_0+L)\lt f(x) \lt g(x)(\epsilon_0+L)\le \epsilon_1(\epsilon_0+L)$$

This turns into:

$$-\epsilon_1(-\epsilon_0+L) \lt f(x) \lt \epsilon_1(\epsilon_0+L)$$

Are my steps correct thus far? Leaving the only thing left is picking a value for $\epsilon_1$ so that I end up with $|f(x)|\lt \epsilon$?

Comment: Your title is wrong or incomplete. ​ If you meant to have the implication as the left part of an if-then, then you should have the right part too. ​ Otherwise, either ": If" should be replaced with "that", or the $\implies$ should be replaced with "then". ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: One flaw at the beginning of the proof:  You seem to starting out saying "for all $\epsilon_1$ and *all* $N_1$" (and likewise with $\epsilon_0$ and $N_0$).  It should be "for all $\epsilon_1$ there *exists* an $N_1$."  There really should be $\exists$ symbols in front of the $N$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler / better to use the laws of algebra of limits which are much more powerful tools than people actually think. An appeal to the definition of limit involving $\epsilon, \delta$ should be avoided unless it is necessary (or explicitly asked by examiner).

Thus for the first problem we see that if $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) = 0$ then $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot g(x) = L \cdot 0 = 0$$

Next problem asks us to prove the converse and here we must have $L \neq 0$ otherwise this converse does not hold. Well, we are given in the question that $L > 0$. Let $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$ and then $$\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{f(x)/g(x)} = \frac{0}{L} = 0$$ and combining this result with the one in previous paragraph we have the following result:

*If $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L \neq 0$ then $$\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x) = 0\Longleftrightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$$*

From the above you can also observe that the conditions $g(x) > 0$ and $L > 0$ are unnecessary. Only requirement is that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)/g(x)$ exists and is non-zero and your conclusions in the question remain valid.

Comment: I like that a LOT more.  Thank you for posting it!

Comment: @RonaldB: Thanks for the positive feedback on my answer. I hope this answer will encourage you to use laws of algebra of limits more and more (in situations where they are applicable).

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. You may choose to fix a value for $\varepsilon_0$ (for example $\varepsilon_0=\dfrac{L}{2}$) and then choose the good value of $\varepsilon_1$ so that $\varepsilon_1(\varepsilon_0+L) \leq \varepsilon$ and $-\varepsilon_1(-\varepsilon_0+L) \geq \varepsilon$.

Comment: You're right, I edit it.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I'm in the right direction. But it seems as though I'm stuck trying to get two different values for $\epsilon_1$ to get $-\epsilon$ on the left side and $\epsilon$ on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use the following way to prove.

1.) Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$, for $\forall \epsilon>0$, there is $N>0$ such that, for $|x|>N$, one has
$$ |g(x)|<\epsilon/(2L), \big|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\big|<\epsilon/2. $$
One also can assume that for $|x|>N$, $|g(x)|<1$.
Then for $|x|>N$,
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)|&=&\big|(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L)g(x)+Lg(x)\big|\\
&\le& \big|(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L)g(x)\big|+|L||g(x)|\\
&<& \epsilon/2+\epsilon/2\\
&=&\epsilon.
\end{eqnarray}
So 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0. $$
2.) Assume $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\not=0$, then
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0 $$
which is against
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L\not= 0.$$